# Change the text color for all print command

Tags: python-3.x, shell

I'm using python 3 to build my system. I want to change all the print commands in my code to print in the same color.

I'm familiar with colorama and the option to print in different color using

```
print(%s Hello World % colorama.Fore.BLUE)
```

Is there any option to define the color of the print only once?
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using something like this:

```
import colorama

def colorprint(text):
    print("{}{}".format(colorama.Fore.BLUE,text))

colorprint("123")
```

Or multiple colors:

```
import colorama

d = {"blue":colorama.Fore.BLUE,
     "black":colorama.Fore.BLACK,
     "yellow":colorama.Fore.YELLOW}

def colorprint(text,color):
    c = d[color]
    print("{}{}".format(c,text))

colorprint("123","yellow")
```